# ASM checking for usage of a class or package

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Using ASM how can I know whether the compiled code in jar is using specific packages or classes rather than checking for a specific method in a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create visitors which record all the packages or classes which are used. (Or only check specific ones)  There are examples of how to create visitors on the ObjectWeb ASM web site.

Do you have a specific question?

Comment: There is no package specific readers as there is not package specific information in the class file format.  You have to create fields, class, method and method body visitors.